# Where can I get a candyfloss for Elizabeth?

Tags: bioshock-infinite

When you're at Battleship Bay with Elizabeth, if you idle in a number of areas you'll find her [skimming stones](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hy15ZrwZO5g) or trying [to lift an exercise ball](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8VIDTqlKL80) and there's a couple of other little things that Elizabeth will do when she is "freed". However, I've seen a couple of screenshots and fan art that shows Elizabeth holding a candyfloss - I've wandered about for a bit in Battleship Bay but can't find where to get one.

Comment: As you wander around, there'll be a man holding cotton candy saying "*Hey there Lady, want some cotton candy?*", shortly thereafter she'll be holding some in her hands. There's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: I just watched those Youtube vids and noticed, these are all from the beach. The man with cotton candy is in an arcade; it's on the same map, though you'll have to walk a little bit farther ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Nolonar is right on this one. He is indeed in Battleship Bay, just up a bit.

When you first get to the arcade (the big room where all the machines, and the first motorized patriot in the cage is), go left, towards the bar.

The cotton candy salesman is standing at the end of the row of machines.

If you need some help locating the spot, just watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2QQmB-HM0W0) video for its whereabouts. (or you could just watch the video if you are inclined)